# azure cosmosdb free tier 100RU

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a pay as you go subscription, initially created via the free azure trial in the visualstudio.com dev essentials site.

On the Azure subscription overview blade, under "Free services for 12 months" mine says

> Storage (GB) - Cosmos DB :  5 GB
>
> 100 Request Units (Hours) - Cosmos DB

When I try create a cosmosdb I cannot create any cosmos DB either FIXED or unlimited with 100 RU. The minimum in all instances is 400RU, and I get an error "Value must be greater than or equal to 400" for RU and cannot continue.

How do i setup the free services then?

Edit: added images

[image: error]
[image: free services]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this 100 RU/s limit you're seeing?

Comment: added them @GauravMantri, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe its a typo as the minimum throughput you can have is 400 RU/s.

Based on the information available on [`Azure Free Account FAQ`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/free-account-faq/), you should get `5 GB of Azure Cosmos DB with 400 reserved in units`.

[image]

Please try to create a `Fixed Size` collection with 400 RU/s throughput and that should work.